# Duplicates to unsatisfactory answers

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that there are a few questions that are basically asking the same thing, but those questions are not satisfactorily answered. For example, I've seen at least two questions on whether a person in debt needs to pay Zakat, but neither have accepted answers. For example:

[How to calculate zakat while in debt?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/how-to-calculate-zakat-while-in-debt)

[Zakat Calculation : Mortgage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/317/zakat-calculation-mortgage)

[Do I need to pay the Zakat if I am accumulating money for a needy purpose?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/do-i-need-to-pay-the-zakat-if-i-am-accumulating-money-for-a-needy-purpose)

In many cases, they are going to choose/upvote an answer they want to believe, rather than the right answer, so people are (rightfully) going to doubt the 'concluded' answer of similar questions and ask the same question again. I'm also afraid that some people would be using the site as a way to win arguments, and keep on giving loaded questions until they get a verbose answer that tells them what they want to hear.

So, how do we deal with these kinds of duplicates?

How would you 'bump' a topic that does not have a satisfactory answer?

If duplicate questions are allowed, would it also be fine to copy and paste the same answer?

Comment: please include links to the questions you are referring to.

Comment: obligatory blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/