# Are zakat math questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Sometimes we get *Zakat math questions*, e.g.,

1. https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31494/17163

   > I have taken Islamic loan from a bank in the amount of 150000 AED in February 2015. ...
2. [calculate my Zakath](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25555/17163)

   > I have gold Jewellery with me moms and wife's total value of 214000 dollars. All the gold weights almost 4500 grams roughly and having it with me for more than five years now. ...
3. [Zakat on Amanat or on Loan given to Some One](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24926/17163)

   > Some one give me $50,000 as a amanat, and I put it in my account that has been intact still in bank account. ...

With Ramadan upcoming, it might be worth deciding if these are on or off topic.

**Question**: Are zakat math questions on topic?

---

Related post: [Duplicates to unsatisfactory answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/17163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call them intrinsically off-topic, but many of them do run the risk of only being helpful exactly once for the exact person asking the exact question at this exact moment (I realize "Too Localized" is no longer a close reason, but that doesn't make these good questions).

I'm not sure if anyone's done so yet, but it's probably worth writing up a canonical "How do I zakat" answer which can cover most if not all of the general cases, and simply closing new questions as a dupe unless they can demonstrate that their *particular* case doesn't fall under the answers scope. But we really shouldn't be catering to users who are just too lazy to work out their own math, once the actual process is pointed out to them.

Answer (score 1):

*Zakat* calculations should be on-topic as they fall under [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh).